# How to fetch first 100 records from Redis

Tags: redis

I am working on small application where I am using redis to hold my intermediate data. After inserting data, I need to reload my data in same order in which i have inserted.

I am using `keys` method to get all keys but the order of returned keys is not same as they were inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain order yourself, by keeping a separate list for inserted keys. So, instead of

```
SET foo, bar
```

you may do something like this:

```
SET foo, bar
RPUSH insert_order, foo
```

Then you can do

```
LRANGE insert_order, 0, 100
```

to get first 100 set fields.

If you want to track actual insertion (and not updates), you can use SETNX, for example. Also, you can use a sorted set instead of a list (as mentioned by @Leonid) Additionally, you can wrap the whole thing in Lua, so that the bookkeeping is hidden from the client code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I am going to have million of records. keeping all record's key in one single record may make my system slow??

Comment: @Alex: It may, or may not. There are tricks (like sharding `insert_order` list). Or you can use real database, because you seem to be wanting one.

Comment: Or you may store your keys in [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) with insertion time as a score, continually cleaning it with `zremrangebyrank` to keep only 100 last entries.

Comment: Actually I am working on a Crawling application and to hold outgoing Urls I wanted to use Redis (Because of fast Insertion and Retrieval) as using URL as key (By this way we can easily handle duplicacy of URLs). But it seems that there is no way to retrieve first n (100/1000) records from redis. Is there any other solution available for that.

Answer (score 1):

For indexing URL and getting the list by inserted order, you should use sorted set:

```
zadd <your_url_list_key> <inserted_time> <url>
```

Detail data for a single url should be stored in a different place. For example, use hash:

```
hset <your_url_data_key> <url> <url_data>
```

It's better if you don't store detail data on redis, so instead of using redis hash, you should save url detail data on mysql.

You can also `md5(url)` before indexing to reduce the size (then the full url value will be stored in url_data).

In my project, sorted set still works ok with about 3mil records (read & write frequently). But you should watch the hash size often, it will grow really fast.